# Display empty UITableView

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

I fill my `UITableView` with data from a `MySQL-DB`.

If my table does not have any entries, I want to display an empty table view.

Can I do it this way:

```
- (UITableView *)returnNumberOfRowsForSection { (=> Pseudocode)
    if (Table is empty) {
        return 0;
    } else {
        return (Entry Count);
    }
}
```

Comment: OK, yes you can ... Found the mistake.

Comment: Assuming a bunch of things about what the pseudocode means and what you'll replace it with, sure.  Why not try real code and see how it goes?  :)

Comment: lol...yeah, real code helps.  It's all good in theory though.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yes, you can. Body must contain 30 characters.